# How to query a Firestore database using React

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new to Firestore.

I have a collection and within that collection a document, which has a few mapped fields.  The approx structure is

```
Questions
  balances
    balances = (map)
      balances = (map)
        hint = (map)
          titleColumn = (map)
            title_1 = (map)
              columnTitle = "Hints"
              linkTitle = "hints"
            title_2 = (map)
              columnTitle = "Other Thing"
              linkTitle = "other"
```

I can query the Firestore using:

```
const collectionId = "Questions";
const documentId = "balances" 
const snapshot = await firestore.collection(collectionId).doc(documentId).get();
```

And I get an object with the data back.  Now I am only interested in the document where the linkTitle = "hint" (so I can get the columnTitle).  Now I could use plain JavaScript to do this, but surely there must be a way to query so only the data I want is returned?  Or am I thinking too much like an old SQL database?

### Edit

```
function App() {
  const firestore = firebase.firestore();
  const collectionId = "Questions";
  const documentId = "balances" 

  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  const [questionTitle, setQuestionTitle] = useState();

  // question things
  const [questionText, setQuestionText] = useState("");
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState("");

  // answer things
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);

  // hint things
  const [hintTitle, setHintTitle] = useState("");

  const [hintDetails, setHintDetails] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {    
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

      if (user) {
        setAuthenticated(true);
      } else {
        setAuthenticated(false);
      }
    });
    const query = firestore
    .collection(collectionId)
    .where('balances.balances.balances.hint.titleColumn.title_1.linkTitle', '==', "hints")
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        //console.log(doc.data());
        console.log("Column Title: ", doc.data().balances.balances.balances.hint.titlecolumn.title_1.columnTitle);
      });
    });

    const getFirebase = async () => {
      const snapshot = await firestore.collection(collectionId).doc(documentId).get();
      const questionData = snapshot.data();     

      // get and set the question title
      setQuestionTitle(questionData.balances.balances.questions.title)

      // get and set the question text and image
      setQuestionText(questionData.balances.balances.fullquestion.question) 
      setImageUrl(questionData.balances.balances.fullquestion.imageUrl) 

      // deal with the answers
      // create a new answer array
      const answerArr = [];  

      // add the answer from firestore to the answerArr
      Object.keys(questionData.balances.balances.answers).forEach(key => {
        answerArr.push(questionData.balances.balances.answers[key]);         
      });
      // set the answers to be the answersArray
      setAnswers(answerArr) 

      // get and set hint title 
      setHintTitle(query)
      
      // get and set all hints
      setHintDetails(questionData.balances.balances.hint)
    }
    getFirebase();    
  }, [firestore]);
```

I am retrieving data from Cloudstore in `useEffect` and using state.  However the querying seems to be eluding me.  Now one extra thing, and this could be me just not getting this at the moment, is that the example query relies on knowing I need to look at title_1 - is there such a thing as a wildcard so that any document under that level would be queried?

Comment: Did you try using a query as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen - I did see that, but I can't get it to work.  Not sure if the data is too wierdly formatted (as I can't even get filter to work in the console) or some other issue (like I am using the collection id and document - and the example doesn't seem to look at this.

Comment: If you tried it, then please edit your questin to show a query you tried, how you processed the results, and a document that you'd have expected back from the query.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question and your Firestore Data Structure;

I replicated your Firestore Data Structure like this:
[image]

And, you'll be able to get the `columnTitle` by using this query that @Frank also mentioned in the comment, also to answer your question

> is that the example query relies on knowing I need to look at title_1 - is there such a thing as a wildcard so that any document under that level would be queried

I updated the code so that any `title` under the `titleColumn` will be displayed.

```
var collection = "Questions";
var document = "balances";

async function getHints(title) {
    const query = db
    .collection(collection)
    .where(`${document}.balances.hint.titleColumn.${title}.linkTitle`, `==`, `hints`)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            var documents = doc.data();
            var result = documents.balances.balances.hint.titleColumn[title];
            console.log(`${title}:`, result);
        });
    });
}

var docRef = db.collection(collection).doc(document);
docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        var titles = doc.data().balances.balances.hint.titleColumn;
        
        for (let title in titles) {
            getHints(title);
        }
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

And, the result will be:

```
title_1: { linkTitle: 'hints', columnTitle: 'Hints' }
```

Comment: Apologies  - didn't know any more replies came in.
I have updated the questsion to show the code I have

Comment: I've updated my post to answer your question.